# Selenium with Python Scripting

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to selenium with python. Tried this sample test script.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def browser():

        driver= webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.get('http://www.gmail.com/')
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.save_screenshot('D:\Python Programs\Screen shots\TC_01.png')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='next']").click()
        message=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='errormsg_0_Email']")
        driver.save_screenshot('D:\Python Programs\Screen shots\TC_03.png')
        name= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Email']").send_keys('gmail')
        driver.save_screenshot('D:\Python Programs\Screen shots\TC_02.png')
        print name
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='next']").click()
        password=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']").send_keys('password')
        driver.save_screenshot('D:\Python Programs\Screen shots\TC_03.png')
        print password
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='signIn']").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.quit()
i=browser()
```

Till the below steps the script runs after that i am getting the error as

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='Passwd']"}
Stacktrace:.
```

Comment: Hi I have used dummy mailid and password as an example.So please dont justify the answer with that.Because you will get error with that mail id and password

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and run the script. Go to the (now opened) browser, right click inside the page and choose 'View source' (or something similar). Search for `"Passwd"`, and if you find it, then copy-paste the entire line into your question. If you don't find it, then it is pretty obvious why your script is not working.

Comment: your function has no return value, so the value i will always be None. If you want the browser to be returned, add a return driver line at the end of your function, and dont quit the browser before the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a wait before clicking password button since it appears after a delay

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Passwd']"))
)
```

Better still, you should configure [implicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#implicit-waits) to your driver at the start of your script, instead of at the end.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def browser():

        driver= webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.get('http://www.gmail.com/')
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_01.png')
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='next']").click()
        #message=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='errormsg_0_Email']")
        driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_03.png')
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        name = driver.find_element_by_name("identifier")
        name.send_keys("Email") # enter correct email to avoid error
        driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_02.png')
        print(name)
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("CwaK9").click()
        password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
        password.send_keys("Password") # enter correct password to avoid error
        driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_03.png')
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        print(password.text)
        driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.quit()
i=browser()
```

The lines commented(with #) should either be commented or should to be removed from your own code.

1. In the first commented line, you are clicking on the next button before filling the email.
2. The element in the second commented line is not available.

Change the folder path to where you want to save the Screenshots.

The values for some elements need to be changed. I have updated them, they are working perfectly fine. you can directly use them. I suggest finding the placement of these exact values with the inspect element to enhance your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The code you made requires just a dynamic waiting technique to be added you may use implicitly wait or explicit wait, and your code works fine. In the code below, both dynamic waiting techniques are shown.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def browser():
    driver= webdriver.Firefox()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get('http://www.gmail.com/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_01.png')
    driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_03.png')
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("name", "identifier")))
    name.send_keys("Email") # enter correct email to avoid error
    driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_02.png')
    print(name)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='VfPpkd-RLmnJb']").click()
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
    password.send_keys("Password") # enter correct password to avoid error
    driver.save_screenshot('/home/webner/Pictures/Gmail_Scrshts/TC_03.png')
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    print(password.text)
    driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.quit()

i=browser()
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of Obsidian's answer. Please consider whether the changes you add warrant a new answer, or whether e.g. commenting is a better fit.